# Using ROW_NUMBER() Function in a WHERE statement in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, row-number

The following works in Postgres:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            product_id,
            product_name,
            price,
            ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY product_name)
        FROM
            products
    ) x
WHERE
    ROW_NUMBER BETWEEN 6 AND 10;
```

My question is why does the following simpler attempt not work?

```
        SELECT
            product_id,
            product_name,
            price,
            ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY product_name)
        FROM
            products
     
WHERE
    ROW_NUMBER BETWEEN 6 AND 10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because window functions, like `row_number()`, are applied to the *result* of the query (in your case that's the inner one), i.e. *after* the `WHERE` clause (not statement) has already taken effect.

Comment: So the variable does not exist in the namespace and cannot be referred to unless it is returned by an inner query.  Interesting.